# MySQL compare two dateTime fields specifying precision

Tags: mysql

With MySQL what is the method of doing a datetime comparison with precision?   Like I want to compare two dateTime fields to see if their equal ignorming minutes and seconds, saying:

```
[compare with precision down to hours] 
Is 2011-05-05 14:32:49 equal to 2011-05-05 14:46:22 ?
=> TRUE
```

I'm not sure there is anything, and google isn't helping (precision just brings up a bunch of results about milli and micro second junk).   Maybe this type of compare is dervied from another function and there isn't a date compare w/ precision in MySQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
DATE(dt1) = DATE(dt2) AND HOUR(dt1) = HOUR(dt2)
```

Take a look at MySql [Date-Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: @Reno: is there a specific reason for which you unaccepted my answer?